# Splitting a String in java at a tab

Tags: java, string, split

I am attempting to split a String into 2 separate Strings, one from the first letter up until a tab, and the other beginning after the tab and ending at the end of the String. I have looked over [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) and have found my problem to be different. I am currently trying to utilize the `split()` method, but with no luck. My code is as follows:

```
        Scanner loadFile = new Scanner(System.in);
        loadFile = new Scanner(menuFile);

        //loops through data and adds into the SSST
        while(loadFile.hasNextLine()){
            String line = loadFile.nextLine();

            String[] thisLine = line.split(" ");

            System.out.println(thisLine[0]);
            String item = thisLine[0];
            String value = thisLine[1];

            menu.put(item, value);
```

I run into my problem at the line `line.split(" ");` because I do not know the argument to provide to this method in order to split at the tab in my String.

`menu` in this code is a separate object and is irrelevant.

**Sample input for this program:**

```
"baguette          400"
```

**Desired output for this program:**

```
String 1: "baguette" 

String 2: "400"
```

Comment: The tab character is written `\t`.

Comment: You're using a space character `" "`, which is distinct from the tab character `"\t"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tab character is written `\t`. The code for splitting the line thus looks like this:

```
String[] thisLine = line.split("\t");
```

More flexible, if feasible for your use case: For splitting on generic white space characters, including space and tab use `\\s` (note the double reversed slash, because this is a regex).

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you!